# Best way to markup an HTML banner

Tags: html, css

The general html structure of my pages is

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="content">
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
</div>
```

I have a 1000px layout with the content centering.

However, for a couple of the pages I have a banner in the content that should expand 100% to the sides of the browser (i.e., beyond the 1000px wrapper).

Should I delete the wrapper div for this page and apply width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; separately? Or should I take the banner outside of the standard wrapper layout? What is a more standard way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382400/outsourcing-css-design-things-to-keep-in-mind-while-writing-html/5382673#5382673) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem and done something like this:

```
.center
{
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="center">
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
    </div>
    <div class="center">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using style="overflow:show" for that content banners parent should allow it to show. Instead of width=100% you might need to use some javascript to get the screens width and make it that width.

Comment: Don’t use JavaScript for something you can do better in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the banner outside of the wrapper.

Comment: I agree. Why would you want to add exclusive rules when you want your banner to NOT be part of your wrapper. i.e. you put it outside the wrapper.